# Weird side slidebar behaviour in jQuery (Chrome and IE)

Tags: jquery, events, position

I am trying to create a slidebar similar to win8 charm bar in my website. It looks a bit like this:

[image]

I want it to function like this :
1. If it's open, then click event on #red will close #green (slide left), hover event on #red will do nothing
2. If #green is closed, then hover on #red will slide #green out.

Here is my jQuery code

```
$("#red").click(function(event) {
    $("#green").removeClass('ready');

    if ($("#green").hasClass('visible')) {
        var width = $("#green").width();
        $("#green").animate({"left":"-"+width+"px"}, "fast");

        $("#green").promise().done(function() {      
            $("#green").removeClass('visible');
            $("#green").addClass('ready');
        });
    } 

});

$("#red").hover(function(event) {
    if ( !($("#green").hasClass('visible')) && $("#green").hasClass('ready') )
    {
         $("#green").animate({"left":"0px"}, "fast");

         $("#green").promise().done(function() {
            $("#green").addClass('visible');
         });
    }
});
```

I think that after the click on #red event script doesn't update the position on #red (it still thinks it sin the same place), and when I move the mouse after click, hover event triggers. Adding classes .ready and .visible seems to work as they should, because if I move the mouse before the sliding is finished, hover is not triggered.

EDIT: It appears to work fine in FF, but not in Chrome and IE.

**EDIT2 : Changing 'hover' to 'mouseenter' fixed it.**

**jsFiddle code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/grhfT/2/

If anyone could help me out here, I'd be grateful. Thank you !

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? If I click, the green hides, then when I hover red the green comes back, just as you mentioned you want.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the behavior of hovering and clicking the red div?

Comment: Sorry, just tested this in FF, there it works fine. The problem happens in Chrome and IE

Comment: Does this answer your requirements better? http://jsfiddle.net/grhfT/3/ (Sizes are changeable in CSS)

Comment: @Itay You probably added extra unnescessary code because I pasted my code where #green is named #toolbar, fixed that now to avoid any more confusion. I took a look at your code, changing 'hover' to 'mouseenter' did the trick. Thank you